# sfSslRequirementPlugin in Symfony2

Tags: ssl, symfony, symfony1

I just want to know if there is a bundle in **symfony2** with the same function of the **sfSslRequirementPlugin**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force areas of your site to use the HTTPS protocol in the security config. This is done through the access_control rules using the requires_channel option. For example, if you want to force all URLs starting with /secure to use HTTPS then you could use the following config:

```
access_control:
    - path: ^/secure
      roles: ROLE_ADMIN
      requires_channel: https
```

See [How to force HTTPS or HTTP for Different URLs](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/security/force_https.html).

Comment: As far as I remember, you can override any bundle's settings in your app's settings.